# How to change the order of elements in listbox and store the values of listbox into an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sharepoint

My listbox(MySelectLinks) is fetching values(AllLinks) from javascript array of objects stored in sharepoint list column.My listbox displays values of AllLinks:

```
[{"AllLinks":"abc","Order":7},{"AllLinks":"ghj","Order":9},{"AllLinks":"abcb","Order":4},{"AllLinks":"ghjnn","Order":1}]
```

I want to change the order by moving elements up and down and save this new order in array.So that the new order can be saved in list.
The following code changes the order but value cant be retained:

```
function MoveUp(lst){
if(lst.selectedIndex == -1)
alert('Please select an Item to move up.');
else
{
if(lst.selectedIndex == 0)
{
    alert('First element cannot be moved up');
    return false
}
else
{
    var tempValue = lst.options[lst.selectedIndex].value;
    var tempIndex = lst.selectedIndex-1;
    lst.options[lst.selectedIndex].value = lst.options[lst.selectedIndex-1].value;
    lst.options[lst.selectedIndex-1].value = tempValue;
    var tempText = lst.options[lst.selectedIndex].text;
    lst.options[lst.selectedIndex].text = lst.options[lst.selectedIndex-1].text;
    lst.options[lst.selectedIndex-1].text = tempText;
    lst.selectedIndex = tempIndex;

}} return false;}
```

Code to display values inside listbox:

```
function populateMyLinks()
{

$.ajax({
url: url,
method: "GET",
headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
success: function (data)
 {

 var blah = JSON.parse(data.d.results[0].AllLinks);
  blah = sortJSON(blah, 'Order');   
 $.each(blah,function(i,result)
 {
   option2 += "<option value='" + result.AllLinks+"'>"+result.AllLinks+"</option>"
 })
 $("#MySelectLinks").append(option2);
 },
  error: function (data)
 {
  alert(data.responseJSON.error);
  }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML for the list?

Comment: @Thiijs -I have edited the question for more clarity.Please let me know if you know the ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have time to add some comments to the code but I hope it pretty much explains itself. I hope it does what you're expecting it to do.

```js
/* === ELEMENT MANIPULATION === */
function moveOptionDown(selectElement) {
  const
    optionElement = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex],
    nextOption = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex + 1];
    
  nextOption.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', optionElement);
}

function moveOptionUp(selectElement) {
  const
    optionElement = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex],
    previousOption = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex - 1];
    
  selectElement.insertBefore(optionElement, previousOption);
}
/* === ELEMENT MANIPULATION === */



/* === ARRAY METHODS === */
function generateOptionArray(selectElement) {
  const
    options = selectElement.options,
    result = [];
  for (var index=0; index < options.length; index++) {
      result.push({
        AllLinks: options[index].textContent,
        Order: index
      });
  }
  
  return result;
}
/* === ARRAY METHODS === */




/* === EVENT HANDLERS === */
function onMoveOptionUp(event) {
  const 
    selectElement = document.getElementById('mySelect');
    
  if (
    selectElement.selectedIndex <= 0
  ) {
    console.log('No option, or the first option, is selected. There is nothing to move');
    return;
  }
  
  moveOptionUp(selectElement);
  const
    optionsArray = generateOptionArray(selectElement);
  console.log(optionsArray);
}

function onMoveOptionDown(event) {
  const 
    selectElement = document.getElementById('mySelect');
    
  if (
    selectElement.selectedIndex === -1 ||
    selectElement.selectedIndex >= (selectElement.options.length - 1)
  ) {
    console.log('No option, or the last option, is selected. There is nothing to move');
    return;
  }
  
  moveOptionDown(selectElement);
  const
    optionsArray = generateOptionArray(selectElement);
  console.log(optionsArray);
}
/* === EVENT HANDLERS === */

const
  buttonUp = document.getElementById('move-up'),
  buttonDown = document.getElementById('move-down');
  
buttonUp.addEventListener('click', onMoveOptionUp);
buttonDown.addEventListener('click', onMoveOptionDown);
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="5">Option 5</option>
  <option value="6">Option 6</option>
  <option value="7">Option 7</option>
</select>

<button type="button" id="move-up">move selected element up</button>

<button type="button" id="move-down">move selected element down</button>
```

Comment: Thanks you @Thijs

Comment: @Thijs-What changes should i make to do vice versa?I mean to bring elements down

Comment: @saumyabhargava I've updated my answer with a move down function.

Comment: @Thijs-It worked perfectly fine.Thanks for the help!

Comment: @saumyabhargava Glad to be of help, good luck with your project!